# Jest testing async function - Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, next.js, node-mocks-http

I want to test my Next.js API functions with Jest using node-mocks-http.
This is the function I want to test:

```js
export default async (
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse
): Promise<void> => {
  const foods = await getFoods()
  res.json(foods)
}
```

This is how my test file looks like:

```js
import { createMocks } from 'node-mocks-http'
import handler from './foods'

  test('api route', async (done) => {
    try{
      const { req, res } = createMocks({
        method: 'GET',
      })
      await handler(req, res)
      expect(res._getStatusCode()).toBe(200)
      done()
    } catch(err){
      done(err)
    }
  })
```

Without the `await getFoods()` call everything works as expected. However with the call I get the Error: `Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.` The `getFoods()` is an async prisma database query.
What is missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Don't mix `done()` and async code also, you don't need the `catch` block, the test will fail if the `async` function rejects.

```js
import { createMocks } from 'node-mocks-http'
import handler from './foods'

  test('api route', async () => {
      const { req, res } = createMocks({
        method: 'GET',
      })

      await handler(req, res)

      expect(res._getStatusCode()).toBe(200)
  })
```

Comment: Using this I'm getting the same 'Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed' Error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have synchronization problem so you should check https://jestjs.io/es-ES/docs/25.x/tutorial-async and there is always the typical timer solution in case your handler function is not working correctly you can try something like this

```
test('api route', async (done) => {
try{
  const { req, res } = createMocks({
    method: 'GET',
  })
  await handler(req, res)
  setTimeout(() => {
    expect(res._getStatusCode()).toBe(200)
    done()
  }, 1000);
} catch(err){
  done(err)
}
```

})

Answer (score 0):

This warning disappears if I add this to my test file:

```
afterAll(async () => {
  await prisma.$disconnect()
})
```